# How do I remove websites from the Limit Adult Websites > Always Allow list in iOS 12

Tags: parental-controls, ios

I have added a website to the 'Always Allow' list in iOS 12 restrictions, but there doesn't seem to be any way to remove it from the list once it has been added.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I suspect there is some permission that is restricting the ability to do this, like the ability to remove bookmarks (i.e. from the allowed websites bookmarks folder) or something, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

**In iOS 12, you can remove an added website from the "Always Allow" list by swiping left to delete.**

In the image below, I created an entry for "StackExchange."  I then swiped left which brought up the *delete* button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommended this answer:

> From Safari: When you try to access a website and it gets blocked, tap "Allow Access" and then the restrictions passcode.From Settings: Go to Settings > General > Restrictions > Enter the passcode. Then go to the Safari settings. There, add your website to "Always allow" list. In your case, adding "wikipedia.org" would be enough.